# How to swap images on mobile/desktop in responsive mode

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, sass

I have a list of images for desktop and mobiles in the following folder structure:

```
img:
    img-1.png
    img-2.png
    img-3.png
    img-4.png
    img-5.png
    img-6.png

img/mobile:
        img-1.png
        img-2.png
        img-3.png
        img-4.png
        img-5.png
        img-6.png
```

I can use the following code to switch desktop `img-1.png`:

```
<span id="switcher">
   <img id="houdini" src="img/img-1.jpg" alt="">
</span> 

<span id="switcher2">
   <img id="houdini2" src="img/img-2.jpg" alt="">
</span>

<span id="switcher3">
   <img id="houdini3" src="img/img-3.jpg" alt="">
</span>

<span id="switcher4">
   <img id="houdini4" src="img/img-4.jpg" alt="">
</span>

<span id="switcher5">
   <img id="houdini5" src="img/img-5.jpg" alt="">
</span>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 489px) {
    span[id=switcher] {
        display:block;
        background-image: url(/mobile/img-1.jpg) !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-position: center !important;
    }
    img[id=houdini] {display: none !important;}
}
```

How can I avoid writing the above CSS for every `img-1` to `6`... Can I pass/access an ID?

Can the use of `!important` be removed?

(Must work on IE8)

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID, classes can be applied to any amount of elements. Also, remove the !importants. This is not needed, unless you're doing something horribly wrong in the first place.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks - thanks for the comments, i'll use them. How about the question of saving to have to write background-image: url(/mobile/img-1.jpg) for each image.. Can i access the img-ID?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973118/incrementing-a-background-image-id-with-sass

Comment: @cimmanon Actually *this* was the first question.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using background image on desktop, you could place each pair of images for desktop/mobile next to each other and toggle their `display` type by giving them the following classes:

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/gisehe/1/edit)**

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/200/f30" alt="houdini" class="visible-mobile">
<img src="http://placehold.it/200/3f0" alt="houdini" class="hidden-mobile">
```

```css
.visible-mobile {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (max-width: 489px) {
  .visible-mobile {
    display: inline !important;
  }

  .hidden-mobile {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice solution. On initial page load, are 2 HTTP requests created?

Comment: @OamPsy Yes. however even by using background images 2 HTTP requests would be created, first to display the image element in HTML (which would be hidden after) and then to load the background image.

Comment: working on mobile optimization myself looking at things to do for images, this post is super easy.  However wont you be loading double the resources now?

Comment: @StevenSmith This answer is not optimized for mobile, nor for desktop. As I mentioned it before, It creates 2 HTTP requests on initial page load. There are new attributes named [`srcset`/`sizes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Specifications) that make UAs ignore the `src` attribute when the media condition matches; But the [browser support is very limited](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) as of now. The other option could be using images as background images within media queries; But still some UAs may create multiple HTTP requests at the same time.

Comment: yeh that's the issue ive been facing, found a server side solution though that works ok, thanks for clarifying that up

Answer (score 2):

```
<picture>

  <source srcset="https://mockuphone.com/static/images/devices/apple-imac2015retina-front.png" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
  <source srcset="https://mockuphone.com/static/images/devices/apple-macbook-grey-front.png" media="(min-width: 500px)">
  <source srcset="https://mockuphone.com/static/images/devices/apple-iphone6splus-spacegrey-portrait.png" media="(max-width: 500px)"> 

  <img src="https://mockuphone.com/static/images/devices/apple-macbook-grey-front.png" alt="Apple Product" id="my-image-1" class="my_image" style="max-width: 100vw; max-height: 100vh;">

</picture>
```

Try this.
 Use min-device-width and/or max-device-width, if you don't want the image to change on browser resize.
 Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically control it

```
$('body').append("<style type='text/css' id="+spanid+">@media screen and (max-device-width: 489px) { span[id="+spanid+"] {/* styles */ } }</style>");
```

For remove style

```
$('#spanid').detach();
```

Or

```
$('#spanid').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="switcher" class="myswitch">
   <img id="houdini" src="img/img-1.jpg" alt="">
</span> 

<span id="switcher2" class="myswitch">
   <img id="houdini2" src="img/img-2.jpg" alt="">
</span>

<span id="switcher3" class="myswitch">
   <img id="houdini3" src="img/img-3.jpg" alt="">
</span>

<span id="switcher4" class="myswitch">
   <img id="houdini4" src="img/img-4.jpg" alt="">
</span>

<span id="switcher5" class="myswitch">
   <img id="houdini5" src="img/img-5.jpg" alt="">
</span>
```

CSS =

```
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 489px) {
    span.myswitch {
      display:block;
      background-image: url(/mobile/img-1.jpg) !important;
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
      background-position: center !important;
    }
    img[id=houdini] {display: none !important;}
  }
```