# Incrementing a background-image ID with Sass

Tags: sass

I have a class which displays a background image:

```
@media all and (min-width: 31.25em) {
    .switch-image {
        display:block;
        background-image: url(/asset/img/img-1.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that I have roughly 30 images (`img-1.png` to `img-30.png`)

How can I save not having to write the above 30 times.

Can I loop through the above and increment `panel-1` by `1` so `panel-2`?

Comment: Could you give an small example of the HTML? Will all 30 elements have the same class (and the first element will get the img-2, the second img-2...) or different classes (`panel-1`, `panel-2`)?

Comment: @nishantjr - example of HTML can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972274/css-image-swapping-removing-duplicated-code/25972502?noredirect=1#comment40667507_25972502

Answer (score 1):

You can use @for look:

```
@media all and (min-width: 31.25em) {
  @for $i from 1 through 30 {
    .switch-image-#{$i} {
      display:block;
      background-image: url(/asset/img/img-#{$i}.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: `.switch-image-#{$i}`?

Comment: @nishantjr - how does using your suggestion impact the HTML markup? Please can you provide example?

Comment: From what I understand of `SASS` (never used it before) this will generate 30 css declarations for `.switch-image` with only the last `background-image` taking effect, and so won't work. [Link to documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_10)

Comment: yes, it generates 30 css declarations. One per iteration. It's not the best practice but all depends on your site and code.